# Django display log in admin interface

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging, django-admin

I'm experimenting with Django and I created a simple model with a name.
The name refers to a logger with the same name.
I want to display all logs of this logger in the admin interface.
How can I do this?

EDIT:
As I mentioned before, I'm experimenting, that's why there is not much code yet.
This is the Model I have. It contains just the name of the object and the name of the logger.

```
class Harvester(models.Model):
   # Name of the harvester for identification
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   logger_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

This Model is added to the admin view in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Harvester)
```

Next thing I want to do is actually create the logger, such as:

```
    logger = get_task_logger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler("{}.log".format(name))
```

This logger should be created, whenever I create a new Harvester as an Admin.

I hope this code makes it less confusing

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show some code!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [Simple production-time debugging in Django – and better error handling](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/simple-production-time-debugging-in-django-and-better-error-handling/)